# Memory-efficient alternatives in python to empty list and append?

Tags: python, list, memory, bigdata, generator

I have a rather large dataset I'm using within python, and using lists is too memory inefficient.

The pseudo-code is like the following:

```
thelist = []
for x in range(N):
    value = function_call()
    thelist.append(value)

more = separate_function_call()

thelist.append(more)
```

I do the standard approach of initializing an empty list, and then append items to this list using an iteration over function calls, plus the output of a separate function call.

My problem is the lists are collectively too big to fit into memory.

Normally, this would be a clear case for generators, e.g.

```
import sys
list_comp = [x ** 2 for x in range(5000) if x % 2 == 0]
gen_exp = (x ** 2 for x in range(5000) if x % 2 == 0)
sys.getsizeof(list_comp)
## 21040
sys.getsizeof(gen_exp)
## 112
```

However, I'm not sure how this work in the above example, as I don't know how to store items in such a data structure except using a list.

What are alternatives to storing items in a massive list like this?

Comment: It depends what you need to do with the list. The 2 most obvious options are that you could process the results one at a time without saving them or you could save results to the disk.

Comment: A generator isn't really a container, it is an iterator. What are you actually going to *do* with this data? In any case, you can just write a generator function... are you asking how to write a generator function? But in that case, you might as well process the data in the for-loop already.

Comment: @kpie How would I save results to disk?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm simply storing items in the list for downstream functions. If I could access them later, that would be useful.

Comment: @EB2127 right. But a generator is going to give you an iterator, will you be able to do the downstream processing on an iterator? Generators aren't magic, they are more memory efficient because they *don't* store all the data at once, rather, the produce the data as you iterate over them. I.E. as kpie said, the option of operating on one of the objects at a time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Downstream processing on an iterator would work. I think I am confused how to do this with the above though---I'm used to writing generators as opposed to list comprehensions, but the above is more difficult, as I'm storing multiple function calls

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think that's my confusion---I was assuming multiple yield's from different function calls in the same generator function would cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could create a generator function to efficiently iterate over the objects with only one in memory at a time:

```
def my_generator(N):
    for x in range(N):
        yield function_call()
    yield another_function_call()

for item in my_generator(1000): # or whatever N
    do_stuff(item)
```

Comment: I think my confusion has been doing yield on difficult function calls....but this would definitely work I think. Thank you for helping me resolve my confusion on this!